# Java Hibernate set min and max column length

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I need to know how to set the min or max annotation for a column in hibernate.

```
@Column (name = "password", 'min = 6, max = 16') // something like this
    private String password;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try @Size constraint

```
@Size(min = 6, max = 16)
```

Refer Example 1.3 in Hibernate documentation
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-gettingstarted.html